# I love programming but I hate all that other stuff I need to do

Tags: work-environment, work-experience, teamwork

I once got a job at the company where I learned programming in their "early days". Now, a few years later, I got the same job at the same company again, but the company has greatly changed.

Now, everything is under "perfect control". There are defined tasks for everything, no programmer is ever free again. Also, instead of just fixing bugs and security holes, everything is evaluated, so maybe some bug never gets fixed (I haven't seen this with security-holes now, but it's very likely that this happens too). We just emerged from a startup-company to a big player, and all the stuff that comes with that.

Of course, I need to document my code (this is not a problem). But I believe it's not really helpful if "documenting my code" means writing quasi-minute-by-minute what I've done to solve a particular problem. I have to log everything, including the exakt times I needed to do some tasks that were assigned to me.

I feel just like a police-officer doing 90% paperwork and only 10% of the work I am supposed to do.

So. I have to admit it: I hate programming. At least in "professional" (that means complex and very hindering in the most cases*) environments.

Right now, I've got only one question: should I quit and look for some other company, maybe study some other subject or do an apprentice in another wholely different area, or should I just accept that my job isn't fun anymore (which is quite hard for me to do)?

*Of course, sometimes there are good reasons to do so. I wouldn't want to work in a nuclear-power-station where the software-developers are very lax. But our software is in-itself not very good and this does not help the least to make this better. When, instead of fixing a simple typo, I need to discuss to the quality-assurance-team for hours, the job just isn't fun anymore.

Comment: "*What should I do?*" is a question for a forum or trusted friend, not a Q&A site.

Comment: Quite honestly, friend, "this is the new normal." The profession of software engineering is now the subject of many, many *laws and regulations(!)* that didn't exist before. Instead of howling in protest, so to speak, *embrace* it. You're being asked to collect detailed activity-data because that data is *needed.* You're observing a strict change-control and change-management process because that, too, is needed. Don't decide that "your job is not fun anymore" just because you're required to do more paperwork now than you prefer or are used to. "It's just different now, that's all ..."

Comment: When I am brought on with a client that takes Agile development too far  my usual response is to escalate it up, log it as a risk on the project, and take a couple opportunities to remind the client that every minute I'm not writing/reviewing code (aka administrative duties like meetings with QA and the rest of the team) costs them roughly **price redacted**.  The ones that are concerned with this scale it back, others seem just fine.  If my client is fine with me spending (x) number of hours a day basically filing paperwork, I am happy to bill an outrageous rate to be a pencil pusher.

Comment: Consider a different career.  I wouldn't hire you as a programmer, and probably anything else for that matter as you don't seem like a team player who can follow company policy.

Comment: @SiX That's too harsh. Following company process is important, but if a person hired as a programmer spends 90% of his time posting nonsense minute by minute updates as against only 10% time doing .... uhm, programming, then surely it is not entirely the employee's fault? Would you work 10 years at this company "diligently following the company process" when at the end of it all, you have gained only about 1 year worth of transferable programming experience and 9 years of company-specific process experience? If yes, then go ahead and demolish the OP.